# Alter Table from nvarchar to float with containing values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi i want to alter my table from nvarchar to float when my table contain values

i'm trying this code:

```
alter table MY_TABLE alter column PRICE float
```

> But i get error Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1 Error converting
>   data type nvarchar to float.

Comment: Isn't that obvious.

Comment: Error message is pretty clear

Comment: Remove all the `varchar` data then run `ALTER` statement

Comment: But i dont want remove them i want to change all my values to float Dynamically

Comment: Hey how is that possible ? How will you convert  `'ABC'` to `float`

Comment: My values arent abc. My values are 9,16 or 3,2 or 5,3. My values are only numbers. Should i user replace comma to dot?

Comment: @user6927546 - Do you want to convert `9,16` to `9.16` then you can replace. But this one `5,3.` has `.` already what is your expected result in this case

Comment: Can i use replace comma to dot  when i insert into my sql for all my insert values?

Answer (score 5):

You have a problem, because some value cannot be converted to a float.

So, get rid of that value first:

```
update my_table
    set price = try_convert(float, price);
```

Then the conversion will work:

```
alter table MY_TABLE alter column PRICE float;
```

I should note:  `float` is a bad data type for a "price" column.  It should really be a numeric or money type.

In SQL Server 2008, use `isnumeric()` instead:

```
update my_table
    set price = NULL
    where isnumeric(price) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

First `Update` the bad records

```
Update MY_TABLE set PRICE = Replace(Replace(Price,',','.'),' ','')
```

Then run the `alter`

```
alter table MY_TABLE alter column PRICE float;
```

To `Insert` into new table

```
Insert into table_name (Price,col1,..)
Select Replace(Replace(Price,',','.'),' ',''),col1,col2,..
From MY_TABLE
```

`FLOAT` is a approximate datatype will not store exact value

Comment: Can i avoid update and then alter table? when i'm using insert to in select * from.. to replace comma to dot.

Answer (score 0):

Review Data that can't be converted

```
Select * from MY_TABLE where IsNumeric(PRICE)=0
```

If this data can be destroyed or has no value otherwise edit where necessary

```
Update MY_TABLE Set PRICE = null where IsNumeric(PRICE)=0
Alter table MY_TABLE alter column PRICE float
```